# Como limpar a tela no TkInter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Há uma forma prática de "limpar" uma tela, dando um `destroy()` em todos os `widgets` de uma vez, sem ter que fazer isso de um por um?

Comment: Está em um *frame* ou outro *container*? Experimentou destruir ele? Se não tem, porque não criar um para conter todos os *widgets* que deseja destruir juntos? Não sei se você sabe que estes controles destroem todos os filhos quando eles são destruídos.

Comment: As `widgets` estão divididas em várias `frames`. Eu tentei destruir as frames para tentar destruir as `widgets` que elas contém junto, mas nada aconteceu(deve ter sido algum problema no código, apesar do `idle` não acusar nenhum erro de sintaxe, vou verificar). Mas mesmo assim, eu ainda teria que destruir as `frames` uma por uma?

EDIT: De fato, foi um probleminha lógico, que já resolvi. Falta de atenção mesmo, rs. Mas deletar frame por frame em programas maiores deve dar um trabalhinho chato.

Comment: De fato deve ser um problema no código. EU acho que isto é a forma mais simples de fazer isto. Erros assim não costumam ser de sintaxe. Você pode colocar todos estes *frames* dentro de outro *frame* que tem como função agrupar tudo o que você quer destruir de uma vez só.

Comment: Gostei dessa dica, facilita bastante o trabalho, Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A técnica básica é criar um *frame* para agrupar todos os controles que deseja destruir, já que cada controle tem por função destruir todos os seus filhos. Lembrando que você pode ter *frames* dentro de *frames* e eles não precisam ser visíveis. É uma forma de organizar os controles. Aí você só precisa destruí-lo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).